# Show/Hide content checkbox using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am making a form and when the user presses on 'Next Section', a new set of input fields which are categorized into 8 sub-forms. Now, based on a few checkboxes, I want to filter out which sub-form appears thereafter.
Suppose there are 5 checkboxes are you are currently on 1st page, now, if you check any of the checkboxes (suppose, checkbox number 4), when clicking on the 'Next Section' button, you should see the relevant page and not the 2nd page.

I'm newbie to AngularJS and looking for an optimum solution. If the solution is in JavaScript, then also, it will work but if it's in AngularJS, that would be more helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is greatly simplified of course and doesn't address validation.  It demonstrates a simplified version of how you can display different content   ('pages') to users when they click on 'Next Section'.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
    <head>
        <title>Validation testing</title>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MyController">

        <form name="form" novalidate>

            <!-- Page 1 Questions-->
            <p ng-if="data.currentPage===1">
                <button type="button" ng-click="data.updateCurrentPage(2)">Next Section</button>
            </p>

            <p ng-if="data.currentPage===1">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    ng-model="data.q1p1"/> Question 1, Page 1
            </p>

            <!-- Page 2 Questions-->
            <p ng-if="data.currentPage===2">
                <button type="button" ng-click="data.updateCurrentPage(3)">Next Section</button>
            </p>

            <p ng-if="data.currentPage===2">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    ng-model="data.q1p2"/> Question 1, Page 2
            </p>

        </form>

        <p ng-if="data.currentPage===3">
                No More questions. 
        </p>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('MyController', function($scope) { 
                $scope.data = {};

                $scope.data.currentPage = 1;

                 $scope.data.updateCurrentPage = function(x){
                    $scope.data.currentPage = x;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```